# Config parser for both python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm looking for solution to use universal code for both python versions of config parser, now I got solution but I'm getting warning about deprecated function.
I'm reading config not from file but from variable.

```py
config = ConfigParser()     
config.readfp(StringIO(variable))
```

I would to use it without warning.

Answer (score 0):

Config parser module has been renamed in Python3 so you should try to import each module with same name. You should use the following import.

```
try:
    # Python 2 only:
    import ConfigParser as Cp
except ImportError:
    # Python 2 and 3 (after ``pip install configparser``)
    import configparser as Cp

config = Cp()     
config.readfp(open(config_file))
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. But you can create a compatible/safe configparser module with readfp method. Or you can use simple "config = Cp.read(config_file)" but it is not too save in some cases.